# Spring paginanation only first page works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So all of this works fine, and in the browser / postman returns two Krytyks with a given name, but when i go to localhost:8080?/krytyk/getbyname/{name}/?page=2 it shows the same thing as on the default page, even though there should be different objects there. Same goes for all the other pages. Any suggestions?

**Repo**

```
public interface KrytykPageableRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Krytyk, Long> {

@Query("select k from Krytyk k where k.name=:name")
Page<Krytyk> findKrytykByName(@Param("name") String name, 
Pageable pageable);
```

}

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/krytyk/getbyname/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Krytyk>> GetByName(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name,
                                               @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer 
pageNo,
                                               @RequestParam(defaultValue = "2") Integer 
pageSize){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(krytykService.findByImie(name, pageNo, pageSize));
}
```

**Service**

```
    public List<Krytyk> findByImie(String name, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize){
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize);

    var paged = krytykPageableRepository.findKrytykByImie(name, paging);

    return paged.hasContent() ? paged.getContent() : new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: Please try `http:l//ocalhost:8080/krytyk/getbyname/{name}/?pageNo=2` (not `...?page=2` ...(parameter)name *is important!!*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `value` parameter to `@RequestParam` like below:

```
//localhost:8080/krytyk/getbyname/{name}/?pageNo=2
@GetMapping(path = "/krytyk/getbyname/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Krytyk>> GetByName(
     @PathVariable(name = "name") String name,                                               
     @RequestParam(value = "pageNo", defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNo,
     @RequestParam(value = "pageSize",defaultValue = "2") Integer pageSize){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(krytykService.findByImie(name, pageNo, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also calling ?pageNo instead of ?page fixed it!